# How to use bibliographystyle plain-fr

Tags: bibtex

I'm writting my thesis and I would like to customize my bibliography in order to respond to the french style. In my pdf I have "title" and I don't want them. I see I could use plain-fr on these website: http://www.cuk.ch/articles/4014 
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backend=bibtex,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,firstinits=false,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
\usepackage{babel}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fr}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\bibliography{bibliobon}

    \begin{document}

    example \cite{author}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

When I try to compile I got this error:
Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid. \bibliographystyle{plain-fr}

How can I use this style?
Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: `plain-fr` is not a `biblatex` style. You'll have either to complie the bibliography with `plain-fr+bibtex` (and delete all commands in relation with `biblatex`) or use `biblatex` and customise the `authoryear` style to obtain exactly what you want. B.t.w. the syntax  `\bibliography{bibliobon}` is not for biblatex: you should use `\addbibresource{bibliobon.bib}` (with the extension) ,and remove `\bibliographystyle`, which is for `bibtex`without `biblatex`.

Comment: @Bernard Hello, Thanks a lot for your quick answer but I don't understand. Because I have backend=bibtex in my preamble. Where I have to put the bibtex? If I put it instead of biblatex I have this error: File `bibtex.sty' not found. ^^M. How to use plain-fr without the bibliographystyle? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `Plain` corresponds to the `numeric` style of  `biblatex`, and it's the default. `babel-french` will take care of most  features – if not all – of `plain-fr`. You also have to load `csquotes` with options `autostyle`, so that it takes `babel` into account and `french=guillemets` for the rules of the *Imprimerie Nationale*.

Comment: Oh! b.t.w., `natbib` and `biblatex` will conflict. Also, unless you have a serious reason, you should use`biber` as a backend if you want to take advantage of all the possibilities of `biblatex/biber` (amongst these, biber understands utf8).

Comment: @Bernard Hello, Thanks again for your answer. Your solution compile with in the premable:\usepackage[french]{babel} and 
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes} but I still have the guillemets. Did you know a another thing I can change? Thanks for your help. (Sorry ctr+k doesn't work in my comment)